# Unable to find curl.h header when cross compiling with "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"

Tags: c++, makefile, arm-linux-gnueabi-g++

I compiled & tested a simple program that calls **libcurl** library using my NetBeans8.2 IDE for C++ and also my own custom-make file using the g++ (c++ 14) compiler on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.

Both Netbeans and my custom-make file are able to find the `#include <curl/curl.h>` that is used do import **libcurl** functions.

**Here is the output from NetBeans build IDE:**

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 75ms)
g++    -c -g -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl -include /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h `pkg-config --cflags libcurl` -std=c++14  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp

mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux

g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/test_proj build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o `pkg-config --libs libcurl`
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xyz/test_proj/test_proj'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xyz/test_proj/test_proj'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 653ms)

**So the IDE compiled the program successfully.**

**Now will attempt this with a make file:**

**Here is my custom make using g++:**

```
EXT_INC = /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h
EXT_LIBS = -lcurl 
CC = gcc
CPP = g++
CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 -I. -I$(EXT_INC) -O0 -fopenmp
LDLIBS= -lm 
LDFLAGS= -L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu


SRCS =  main.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

BIN_NAME = main

all: $(BIN_NAME)

$(BIN_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(EXT_LIBS)

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(EXT_LIBS)

clean: 
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(BIN_NAME)
```

Here is my Makes(using g++ as compiler) output:

xyz@xyz-Virtual-Machine:~/test_proj/test_proj$ make -f ./Makefile_g_plus_plus
make: Circular main.cpp <- main.cpp dependency dropped.
g++ -g3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h -O0 -fopenmp -o test_proj main.cpp -L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -lm  -lcurl
cc1plus: warning: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h: not a directory

**There is a warning but binary is actually built & I tested it without errors.**

**Actual issue:**

**If I replace g++ with the cross compiler (arm-linux-gnueabi-g++)** then the cross compiler complains that it can't find the "curl.h" header?

**Here is the same make file as above but with arm-linux-gnueabi-g++:**

```
EXT_INC = /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include
EXT_LIBS = -lcurl 
CC = arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CPP = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 -I. -I$(EXT_INC) 
LDLIBS= -lm 
LDFLAGS= -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib


SRCS =  main.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

BIN_NAME = test_proj

all: $(BIN_NAME)

$(BIN_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(EXT_LIBS)

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(EXT_LIBS)

clean: 
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(BIN_NAME)
```

**Here is the output of the make with compiler set to arm-linux-gnueabi-g++:**

arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -g3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h -O0 -fopenmp -o main main.cpp -L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -lm  -lcurl
cc1plus: warning: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h: not a directory
main.cpp:7:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
7 | #include <curl/curl.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile_Arm:19: main] Error 1

**How can I make  arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ cross compiler OR make resolve the "curl.h" header?**

Thanks

Comment: Your cross compiler probably has its own include path, and almost certainly has its own library path.  I've also never seen `-I` used to pass a specific file, since as far as I'm aware it's supposed to take a directory.

Comment: @StephenNewell I updated the make file & Im getting the same error. Do i need to build libcurl specifically for arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ before attempting to build my own program?

Comment: You'll need to cross-compile libcurl to get the library for sure.  The command line you posted shows you're passing an explicit file with `-I` which is still incorrect, it needs to be a directory.  Be aware that it's possible curl.h is different in different environments as well, so you might want to use whatever comes with the cross-compiled libcurl.

Comment: @StephenNewell I created a new post, since the original issue was fixed & now Im on another issue. Although the cross-compilation is not complete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616572/attempting-to-cross-compile-libcurl-for-arm-linux