# Attempting to cross compile libcurl for ARM Linux

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, libcurl

**I'm attempting to cross-compile a simple C++ program that uses the libcurl for ARM Linux target, **.

I need to 1st cross-compile libcurl itself & provide the path of the cross-compiled headers/libs to my makefile.

Im running the compilation on Ubuntu 20.4.

**Anyways I followed these instructions:** https://curl.se/docs/install.html, **refer to the section titled "Cross compile"**

**Based on that document I followed these step**s:

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
export LD=arm-linux-gnueabi-ld
export RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include"

mkdir libcurl_repo
cd libcurl_repo

git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git

cd curl

cmake . 

#error was here:
./configure --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include --exec-prefix=/usr/local --disable-shared --enable-static --without-ssl

make -j4 

make install
```

**There error than Im getting is:**

```
./configure: line 8049: syntax error near unexpected token `Windows'
./configure: line 8049: `LT_LANG(Windows Resource)'
```

Comment: Why not run cmake? `CPPFLAGS` is useless, curl is a C project.

Comment: You'll be much better off using a release than cloning the current master branch which is not unlikely to be buggy/broken. You seem to be missing a step in what you say you did, the repository doesn't contain `configure` so you must have done something to generate that?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I issued `cmake .`

Comment: I'd be surprised if running cmake generates the configure script and that isn't following the instructions that you've linked to. Either use a release then follow the instructions or use the instructions in the git repository to generate the configure script then follow the instructions. If you want to use cmake then you'll need to follow the normal cmake cross build procedures